# Robocopy to move files and log only source filenames

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I've been trying to do this for a few hours now and I hoped it would be simple. Users would be able to go to a network folder `uploads` and right-click paste their uploads to a `new` folder inside `uploads`. (I don't want them to have access to the "new" folder except to paste to it.)

Inside the `new` folder is another folder named `filed`. I created a batch file to use `robocopy` to move the newly uploaded files from `new` to `filed` and create a log in the `uploads` folder so the users will be able to see a list of the files that were uploaded. It works ok.

I don't want `robocopy` to log the destination folder, only the source. (or just the destination), but I don't want the same file logged again -  I tried `/xo`, but that doesn't do it). I'd also prefer only filenames, not paths. (I used /`ndl` but it doesn't seem to work.) I also don't want the monitor: waiting text. Can I do this with `robocopy`? is there a better way? It also logs the roboc.bat file unless I make it hidden and I don't think it should.

I know I have a bunch of needs here, but I'm new to this. Thanks!

```
ROBOCOPY C:\uploads\new C:\uploads\new\filed /xf *.bat /mov >> C:\uploads\log.log /ts /ns /nc /ndl /njh /njs /nosd /nodd /mon:1
```

Later...So i figured out /xx and it worked the way i needed it to. If I could just get it to stop writing the monitor: waiting text to the log, it would be good enough.

Eric, tried @ECHO OFF and it didn't make a difference. I'd really like to exclude the all the Started: text AND the Monitor: text - Thanks for trying though!

Comment: As far as not writing to your monitor, do you have `@ECHO OFF` at the top of your script?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `robocopy`? if you'd go for `xcopy`, it could list only the source files (as long as you don't give the `/F` switch)...

Comment: is there a way to monitor in xcopy like /mon:1 in robocopy?